# How to make icon inline with text in button bootstrap 5

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

can anyone help

```
<div class="col-auto mt-lg-0 mt-2">
  <a href="#" style="--bs-btn-font-size: .95rem;" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
     <i class="bi bi-download"></i>
     Download
  </a>
</div>
```

I have tried using `d-flex align-items-center` in tag `a` but still doesn't work

result
[icon button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG5L0.png)

Answer (score 0):

wrap it on div with class 'btn-group'

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" >
      <span>
        <i class="bi bi-download"></i>
        Download
      </span>
    </button>
  </div>
```

Comment: I've tried it, but it still doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

You just have to give a span tag and add m-auto class to that span tag. Try below code:

```html
<div class="col-auto mt-lg-0 mt-2">
    <a href="#" style="--bs-btn-font-size: .95rem;" class="btn btn-outline-secondary d-flex align-items-center">
      <span class="m-auto">
        <i class="bi bi-download me-2"></i>
      Download
      </span>
    </a>
  </div>
```